# Regular Expressions for Japanese in Lua

Tags: regex, unicode, lua, cjk

I want to process japanese vocabulary in Lua (LuaTeX to be specific). The vocabulary is stored in a text file which is to be read. While reading each line of the file the words should be matched by a regular expression (lines are written like: 
`| がくせい | student |`):

```
function readFile(fn)
   local file = assert(io.open(fn, "r"))
   local contents = file:read("*a")
   file:close()
   return contents
end

function processTest(contents)
   for line in contents:gmatch("%a+") do
      print(line)
   end
end

a = readFile("vocabulary.org")
processTest(a)
```

The problem now is that only the english words are printed:

```
student
```

I have to mention that I'm new to Lua and LuaTeX, so if there is a better approach to it I would be happy to know.

Anyway, is there any possibility to get the Japanese words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `%a` for this.  It only matches a single octet (locale-dependent but usually only a byte that encodes a letter in ASCII or Latin-1.)

To match UTF-8 encoded letters you would need to break them down into ranges of bytes, as in the example [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode).

For example some patterns for UTF-8-encoded Hiragana might include:

```
(\227\129[\129-\191])
(\227\130[\128-\160])
```

A full list of patterns to match *all* unicode letters (which would need to include hundreds of subranges) would be unwieldy.

Comment: How to use string.gsub to match the CJK chars?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Lua guru, but I think you are probably out of luck.  Lua doesn't consume Unicode files "natively," as it were.  It just treats what it reads as a series of bytes and doesn't do any interpretation on it.  In particular, your gmatch() call isn't likely to do what you want.

There was a big discussion about i18n on the mailing list recently [here](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-01/msg00832.html).  This discussion [here](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-01/msg00405.html) may also help.